# Disabled samsung keyboard- now can't turn on my s3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, encryption

I am in a weird situation. Few days back (I believe) I disabled samsung keyboard using nobloat app as i use adaptxt all time.
But i have an encryption password and as samsung keyboard is disabled, i cant turn my phone on. I click on the text box for entering the device storage password when it boots, nothing happens (obviously) :(

I will appreciate any ideas or hacks to work around this issue, so that i will be able to use my phone.

Is there a way using command line to restore my keyboard app? I would ideally not want to restore/format my phone.

Thanks!

Also i am travelling and just have my ipad. Any ideas to solve this problem without use of computer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have *USB Debugging* enabled on your device? Probably this won't do either as it most likely requires the de-cryption to be done before, but you *might* be able to do something with `adb` remotely. If not, the usual last-ressort remains: factory-reset...

Comment: I believe usb debugging is enabled.

Comment: And do you have the possibility to connect your device via USB to a computer with the SDK (or at least ADB tools) installed? Then you could check whether it is listed with the `adb devices` command and, if so, you can access it with e.g. `adb shell` (I doubt this due to the encryption, but who knows: it might ask you for the key there, just a small hope).